# (Almost) found a counterexample to the Beal conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures

The Beal Conjecture states that if $A^x + B^y = C^z$, where $A, B, C, x, y, z$ are positive integers and $x$, $y$, $z$ are $≥ 3$, then $A$, $B$, and $C$ have a common prime factor.

There is some reward for a proof or a counterexample.

After a few minutes of searching, I found:

$9998500104995450136496997050049356506434949950300298635004549989500014
99999$

$$ +$$
$9998400119994400181995632080078856012869885600800795632018199944000119
9998400001$
$$ = $$

$9998500104995450136496997050049356506434949950300298635004549989500014
9999900000.$

---

Note that

- $9998500...499999 = 99999^{15}$,
- $9998400...400001 = 9999800001^8$, and
- $9998500...900000 = 9999700002999990^5$.

So is the conjecture solved? Unfortunately, no. It turns out that the greatest common divisor of these numbers is $99999$, so this cannot be a counterexample to Beal's conjecture according to the definition above.

Now the question arises, is there a list (maybe in the OEIS) about ''near misses'' to counterexamples of Beal's conjecture? Or perhaps a list of known general solutions to $A^x + B^y = C^z$ where I can add this term?

Comment: How old is Bean's conjecture ?

Comment: @ErikSatie Beal's conjecture was formulated by Andrew Beal in 1993. So around 30 years old.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the reward for a counterexample would be (if there is one at all) much much lower than for a proof. Even a very rich man would not risk a huge amount of money for a counterexample (that might be found at any time). That such a large example was found so quickly should have told you that it cannot be very difficult to find an example , if the gcd need not be $1$. A "near miss" is rather an instance with gcd $1$ and a small difference between the values of the two sides.

Comment: @ErikSatie Beal's conjecture :) Maybe , Mr. Bean created similar conjectures as well :) :)

Comment: @Peter Oh my bad ! Beal's conjecture ... :-)

Comment: There are so many infinite families of trivial solutions with $\gcd(A,B,C)>1$ that listing them seems like a rather monumental task not worth the effort.

Comment: @Peter The official website of the reward says that you still get 1M dollars for a counterexample.

Comment: This would be an insane offer , but to be fair the offers for huge primes (that could be found by everyyone in principle) are not much more reasoanable , not quite a million , but still ridicoulous high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a list in the oeis for equations of this type. Even if it does contain sequences of this type the oeis isn't really the place for this kind of problem. The more variables in an equation the harder is becomes to catalog. For example these three sequences A050787, A050788 and A050789
catalog solutions to the equation $A^3+B^3=C^3-1$. (one sequence for each variable.) These sequences are organized by increasing values of $C$. In the $A^x+B^y=C^z$ case there would be six sequences which would probably be organized by increasing values $C^z$. Having one equation spread over six sequences is bad enough but there are other problems. Unlike the Cube sequences mentioned earlier there would be whole bunch of duplicates. For example $256+256=512$ can be represented eight different ways assuming that it takes the form $A^x+B^y=C^z$ where $A,B,C,x,y,z\in\Bbb{N}\space |\space x,y,z\ge 3$.

$2^8+2^8=2^9$, $\quad 4^4+2^8=2^9$, $2^8+4^4=2^9$, $\quad 4^4+4^4=2^9$,
$2^8+2^8=8^3$, $\quad 4^4+2^8=8^3$,
$2^8+4^4=8^3$, $\quad 4^4+4^4=8^3$

The number of duplicates gets larger and larger as the numbers get lager. Also unlike the cube sequences it is fairly trivial to construct an infinite number solutions to  $A^x+B^y=C^z$ when $A,B,C$ share a factor. I can even do so using the very large example in the original post. For the sake not typing large numbers that nobody is going to read including myself. I will represent the bases of the power numbers in the example of the original post as $p,q,r$ respectively. Therefore $p^{15}+q^8=r^5$. One way I could create an infinite number of solutions is to multiply by $d^{120}$ where $d\in\Bbb{N}\space|\space d>1$ Then we would have $\left(pd^8\right)^{15}+\left(qd^{15}\right)^{8}=\left(rd^{24}\right)^{5}$. Another way I could do this is to multiply by $p^{40d}$. Then we would have $p^{40d+15}+\left(qp^{5d}\right)^{8}=\left(rp^{8d}\right)^{5}$. When looking at a particular sequence in the oeis it displays around 30 terms. Sometimes there can be links to text files with 100,000 terms. Even with 100,000 terms it wouldn't even come remotely close to the large example found by the op. There is no point in adding that example to the oeis.

Comment: Very good answer !(+1)

Answer (score 2):

$99999^{15}+9999800001^8=9999700002999990^5$
$99999^{15}+(99999^2)^8=(10\cdot 99999^3)^5$
$99999^{15}+99999^{16}=10^5\cdot 99999^{15}$
$99999^{15}+99999\cdot 99999^{15}=100000\cdot 99999^{15}$

$a^{15}+a\cdot a^{15}=(a+1)\cdot a^{15}$

Let $a+1$ be a fifth power, say $a+1=b^5$, and we can rewrite as:

$a^{15}+a\cdot a^{15}=b^5\cdot a^{15}$
$a^{15}+(a^2)^8=(b\cdot a^3)^5$

In general, initially equal exponents can be manipulated fairly easily to produce an equation that has unequal exponents.

Answer (score 1):

You can have infinitely false solution (which explain the down-vote) :

Consider $a=0.25$:

$$\left(\frac{1}{16}\cdot\frac{2x}{x+1}\right)^{4}+3^4\left(\frac{1}{16}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{4}x}{x+1}\right)^{4}-\left(\left|2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2x}{x+1}-1\right|\right)^{4}=0$$

You have a false solution around $x=8$ but for $n=8$ :

$$\gcd\left(4096\left(8+1\right)^{4}\cdot\left(\left|2a\cdot\frac{2\cdot8}{8+1}-1\right|\right)^{4},4096\left(8+1\right)^{4}\cdot3^4\left(\frac{1}{16}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{4}8}{8+1}\right)^{4}\right)=1$$

Are you agree ?

Ps: It can be strenghened as you wish